# Some system fonts cannot be found

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm running an up-to-date Arch system and using `xelatex`. With some documents, I'm getting the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[ClearSans-Regular.ttf]/OT', contains '['

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "ClearSans-Regular" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

However, the font in question is definitely installed on my system, I can use it in other applications and:

```
22:46 $ fc-list | grep ClearSans-Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/ClearSans-Regular.ttf: Clear Sans:style=Regular
22:47 $ fc-match ClearSans-Regular
ClearSans-Regular.ttf: "Clear Sans" "Regular"
```

Also, this problem is not limited to this particular font but happens with some other fonts as well.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:** Minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .ttf}
\setsansfont[UprightFont = *-Regular]{ClearSans}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: The UprightFont key is imho still broken, https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/291.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think that's the problem, if I replace the line with `\setsansfont{ClearSans-Regular}` the error is still the same

Comment: Is the font found with `\setsansfont{ClearSans-Regular.ttf}`? What are the versions of your fontspec and xetex?

Comment: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux)` and fontspec: `{2017/07/23}{2.6c}`

Comment: Oh, and the `\setsansfont{ClearSans-Regular.ttf}` variant produces the same error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It doesn't give an error, though. That's not to say it works, but the document in the example never actually uses the font, so the error isn't use-dependent.

Comment: You ought not need to specify the font by name. If you comment the default feature line and use `\setsansfont[UprightFont = *-Regular]{Clear Sans}` on the next line, does it work? (Note the space in the font name.)

Comment: You're lucky to get an error, actually. I wish XeTeX gave me an error rather than throwing my computer into frenzied mode and forcing me to kill the process. (LuaTeX is much better behaved.)

Comment: @cfr No, that doesn't work either, no variant I could think of works (spaces, no spaces, with the regular option, without it, etc.) I think there's probably something broken about how xelatex/fontspec looks for fonts on my system.

Comment: @kralyk -- You are setting `\setsansfont` and in your document you don't say `\sffamily`, how would you activate the chosen font? Either add `\sffamily` or use `\setmainfont` instead.

Comment: @AboAmmar That's completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Are other fonts in this location found? What does lualatex say?

Comment: I'm sure there was another question about this on Arch. Does anybody know where it is?

Comment: I've seen one Arch-specific, but the answer didn't help...

Comment: `\setsansfont{clearsans}` works with luatex but fails with xetex.  Strange.

Comment: `\setsansfont{Clear Sans}` without calling `\defaultfontfeatures` works with `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)`.